# Evaluate the series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k e^{- k^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Using the integral test for convergence, it is quite obvious that the series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}  k e^{- k^2}$ converges. How do we evaluate the series?

Comment: Does it have a "closed form"?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I fixed it