# How to evaluate $\sum\limits_{x=0}^\infty \text{erfc}(x)= 1.1619990479471263635323…?$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-numbers, special-functions, gamma-function, error-function

This will be the $5$th in a series of an infinite series of a single function. Here are 2 related sums:

> [A Kelvin-Bessel Sum: $$\mathrm{\sum\limits_{\Bbb N} ker(x)+i\ kei(x)= \sum\limits_1^\infty K_0\left(\sqrt ix\right)= 0.133691752… - 0.7256312077… i}$$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4253802/closed-form-of-mathrm-sum-limits-bbb-n-kerxi-keix-sum-limits-1-in)

and

> [On $$\mathrm{\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \left(C(n)-\frac{\sqrt\pi}{2\sqrt2}\right)+ \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \left(S(n)-\frac{\sqrt\pi}{2\sqrt2}\right)}$$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4223393/on-mathrm-sum-limits-n-0-infty-leftcn-frac-sqrt-pi2-sqrt2-right)

Our goal sum uses the [Complementary Error function](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/Erfc/) integrating term by term. Note the [Fresnel Integrals](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral). There are also [**Gamma type functions**](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/):

$$\sum_{\Bbb N^0}\text{erfc}(x)=\sum_{x=0}^\infty \text{erfc}(x) =\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(n-\sum_0^n \text{erf}(x)\right)= \frac{2}{\sqrt \pi}\sum_{x\in \Bbb N^0}\int_x^\infty e^{-t^2} dt= \sum_{x\in \Bbb N^0}\left(1-\frac 2\pi \int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(2tx)}{te^{t^2}}dt\right)=\sum_{x\in\Bbb N^0}\left(1 - (1 + i) \left(\text C\left(\frac{((1 - i) z)}{\sqrt\pi}\right) - i\,\text S\left(\frac{((1 - i) z)}{\sqrt\pi}\right)\right)\right)=\sum_{\Bbb N^0}\text{erf}(x,\infty)= \frac{1}{\sqrt \pi}\sum_{\Bbb N^0}Γ\left(\frac12,x^2\right)= \sum_{\Bbb N^0}Q\left(\frac12,x^2\right) =\frac{1}{\sqrt \pi} \sum_{\Bbb N^0}x \text E_\frac12 \left(x^2\right)= \frac{1}{\sqrt \pi}\int_1^\infty t^{-\frac12}\sum_{x\in\Bbb N^0}xe^{-tx^2}dt =1.16199904794712636353230832245579717…$$

As @JohnBarber found:

$$\sum_{\Bbb N^0}\text{erfc}(x) =1+\frac{2}{\sqrt\pi}\int_1^\infty \lfloor x\rfloor e^{-x^2} dx$$
The final integral-sum representation reminds me of a [**Differentiated Jacobi Theta function of the Third Kind**](https://functions.wolfram.com/EllipticFunctions/EllipticThetaPrime3/02/). Here is a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3252623/evaluate-the-series-sum-k-1-infty-k-e-k2?noredirect=1) about it although there are others.

How can I evaluate the constant? Please correct me and give me feedback!

Comment: Note: Neither [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1.161999047947126363532308) nor [the inverse symbolic calculator](http://wayback.cecm.sfu.ca/cgi-bin/isc/lookup?number=1.1619990479471263635&lookup_type=simple) gave me a suitable closed form.

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch All other questions of $\sum f(x)$ where $f(x)$ is any special function, not a combination thereof, gave closed forms. Is it possible to get an integral representation? Thanks. Note the value may be slightly different as I used up to 900 terms.

Comment: Is there any reason to believe there is a closed form?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Well [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4222589/on-mathrm-sum-limits-x-1-infty-cix) had a closed form, but if there are none, then an integral representation suffices.

Comment: Is there any reason to believe there is an integral representation?

Comment: @MikeHawk [Abel-Plana formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel–Plana_formula). This series does have an integral representation. Even if the linked formula does not work, other theorems should work. Is there any reason for not believing in an integral representation?

Comment: Is there something about that formula that is unsatisfactory to you? Otherwise it seems you have answered your own question.

Comment: @MikeHawk    Can you write the constant without using summation notation? It is also possible one can put it into a better form or why would I ask the question?

Comment: "better" in what way? You asked for an integral representation; if the Abel-Plana representation is not to your liking, then please clarify your question to say exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: @MikeHawk like [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/184098/evaluation-of-sum-limits-n-0-infty-left-operatornamesin-frac-pi2?noredirect=1&lq=1), please try to evaluate this erfc question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129793/discussion-between-tyma-gaidash-and-mike-hawk).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about this:
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \mathrm{erfc}(n) \;=\;
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_n^{\infty}e^{-t^2}\, dt
$$
In this sum of integrals, the interval $[0,1)$ will be counted only once, in the $n = 0$ term. The interval $[1,2)$ will be counted twice, in the $n = 0$ and $n = 1$ terms. And so on. This means we can write:
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \mathrm{erfc}(n) \;=\;
\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^{\infty}\, \lfloor t+1\rfloor \,e^{-t^2}\, dt
$$
I don't know if this is the sort of alternative integral representation you were looking for.

Edited to add two other ways to write this expression:

**First way**: The quantity $\lfloor t+1\rfloor$ can be written as
$$
\lfloor t+1\rfloor \;=\; (t+1) \;-\; S(t)\, .
$$
where $S(t)$ is a sawtooth wave of period $1$ with minimum value $0$ and a maximum value $1$. One way we could write this sawtooth is as $S(t) \,=\, t\;\mathrm{mod}\;1$. Substituting this expression for $\lfloor t+1\rfloor$ into the integral above and using the fact that $\int_0^{\infty} dt \, (t+1)\,e^{-t^2} = (1+\sqrt{\pi})/2$ yields
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \mathrm{erfc}(n) \;=\;
\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\left[\frac{1}{2}(1+\sqrt{\pi}) \;-\; \int_0^{\infty}dt\, S(t)\, e^{-t^2}\right].
$$
Evaluating this numerically in Mathematica with 20 digits of precision yields $1.16200283409802758182$, which is greater than Mathematica's estimate for the original sum by roughly $3.8\times {10}^{-6}$. Close enough for the vagaries of numerically evaluating weird sums and integrals.

**Second way**: Poisson's summation formula states that if $f(x)$ is a function and
$$
\hat{f}(q) \;=\; \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} dx\, e^{-i q x}\, f(x)
$$
is its Fourier transform, then
$$
\sum_{n = -\infty}^{+\infty} f(n) \;=\; \sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} \hat{f}(2\pi n)\, .
$$
Define the *even* function $f(x) = \mathrm{erfc}(|x|)$. Since $f$ is even, we can write the original sum as
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \mathrm{erfc}(n) \;=\; \frac{1}{2}f(0) \,+\,\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n = -\infty}^{+\infty} f(n)
\;=\; \frac{1}{2} \,+\,\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n = -\infty}^{+\infty} \hat{f}(2\pi n)\, .\hspace{0.5in}\text{(1)}
$$
The Fourier transform of $f$ is:
\begin{align}
\hat{f}(q) &\;=\; \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} dx\, e^{-i q x}\, \mathrm{erfc}(|x|)\\[0.1in]
&\;=\; 2\int_0^{+\infty} dx\, \cos(q x)\, \mathrm{erfc}(x)\hspace{0.5in}\text{Since $\mathrm{erfc}(|x|)$ is even}\\[0.1in]
&\;=\; \frac{4}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^{+\infty} dx\, \cos(q x)\,\int_x^{\infty}dt\, e^{-t^2} \hspace{0.5in}\text{Definition of $\mathrm{erfc}$}\\[0.1in]
&\;=\; \frac{4}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^{+\infty} dt\, e^{-t^2}\,\int_0^t dx\, \cos(q x) \hspace{0.5in}\text{Reverse order of integration}\\[0.1in]
&\;=\; \frac{4}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^{+\infty} dt\, e^{-t^2}\,\frac{\sin(q t)}{q}\\[0.1in]
&\;=\; \frac{4}{\sqrt{\pi}}\frac{D(q/2)}{q} 
\end{align}
In the last line above, "$D$" is the Dawson function according to the third definition [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dawson_function#Definition).
This expression for $\hat{f}(q)$ is valid everywhere except at $q = 0$, where
$\hat{f}(0) = 2/\sqrt{\pi}$. Plugging all of this into (1) results in:
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \mathrm{erfc}(n) 
\;=\; \frac{1}{2}\left[1 + \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} \,+\,\frac{8}{\sqrt{\pi}}\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{D(\pi n)}{2\pi n}\right]\, .
$$
Evaluating this numerically in Mathematica yields $1.16199904795$.

Comment: The integral from 0 to 80 only [gives 1.029…](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+floor%28x%2B1%29+e%5E%28-x%5E2%29+from+0+to+80) which is a bit off from the 1.16… value, but thanks.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo! I forgot to include the prefactor in front of the integral. Now it should be fine.

Comment: Is it possible to evaluate the integral into a new summation representation or possibly a closed form?

Comment: It _is_ possible to rewrite this thing in a couple of different ways: As an integral with respect to a sawtooth wave, or as an infinite sum over Dawson functions. I'll edit my answer later to outline these. There are probably other ways as well. I haven't been able to find a closed-form solution. I doubt there is one.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will use your techniques extensively for upcoming problems.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a general approach that I believe is valid when $f(0)$ is finite and the sum over $f(x)$ converges. This approach uses convolution with the [Dirac comb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_comb) $\operatorname{\text{Ш}}(x)$ where Mellin convolution, defined in formula (1) below, is denoted as $*_\mathcal{M}$ and Fourier convolution, defined in formula (4) below, is denoted as $*_\mathcal{F}$.

---

$$\left[g(x)\,*_\mathcal{M}\,f(x)\right](y)=\int_0^\infty g(x)\,\frac{f\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)}{x} \, dx\tag{1}$$

---

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty f(n)=-\frac{1}{2}\,f(0)+\left[(x\,\operatorname{\text{Ш}}(x))\,*_\mathcal{M}\,f\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right](1)=-\frac{1}{2}\,f(0)+\int_0^\infty\operatorname{\text{Ш}}(x)\,f(x)\,dx\tag{2}$$

$$\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty f(n)=\frac{1}{2}\,f(0)+\left[(x\,\operatorname{\text{Ш}}(x))\,*_\mathcal{M}\,f\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right](1)=\frac{1}{2}\,f(0)+\int_0^\infty\operatorname{\text{Ш}}(x)\,f(x)\,dx\tag{3}$$

---

$$\left[g(x)\,*_\mathcal{F}\,f(x)\right](y)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x)\,f(y-x)\,dx\tag{4}$$

---

$$\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^\infty f(n)=\left[f(x)\,*_\mathcal{F}\,\operatorname{\text{Ш}}(x)\right](0)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\,\operatorname{\text{Ш}}(-x)\,dx=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\operatorname{\text{Ш}}(x)\,f(x)\,dx\tag{5}$$

---

Using the following analytic representation of the Dirac comb where the evaluation frequency $f$ is assumed to be a positive integer

$$\operatorname{\text{Ш}}(x)=\underset{f\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(1+2\sum\limits_{k=1}^f\cos(2 \pi k x)\right)\tag{6}$$

and the following related integral results

$$\int_0^\infty\text{erfc}(x)\,dx=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\tag{7}$$

$$\int_0^\infty 2\cos(2 \pi k x)\,\text{erfc}(x)\,dx=\frac{2\,F(\pi k)}{\pi ^{3/2}\,k}\tag{8}$$

and noting that $\frac{1}{2}\text{erfc}(0)=\frac{1}{2}$, formula (3) above leads to the following result for $f(x)=\text{erfc}(x)$ where $F(x)$ is [Dawson's integral](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DawsonsIntegral.html):

$$\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\text{erfc}(n)=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}+\frac{2}{\pi^{3/2}}\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\frac{F(\pi k)}{k}\tag{9}$$

---

Mathematica gives the numerical approximation of formula (9) above as $\sum_\limits{n=0}^\infty\text{erfc}(n)\approx 1.1619990479420759$.

---

Note formula (9) above appears to be consistent with [the answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4255109) posted by [John Barber](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/73626/john-barber) which uses the floor function $\lfloor x\rfloor =x-\text{SawtoothWave}[x]$. Also note the floor function is the integral of the Dirac comb and has the following analytic representation where the evaluation frequency $f$ is assumed to be a positive integer.

$$\lfloor x\rfloor=\underset{f\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(x-\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{\pi}\sum\limits_{k=1}^f\frac{\sin(2 \pi k x)}{k}\right)\right)\tag{10}$$

Comment: [+1], but the Dawson integral is just another error function. Both you and the other answerer used the same method. The Dirac Comb is s good method as [seen here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4222589/on-mathrm-sum-limits-x-1-infty-cix).

Comment: @TymaGaidash I didn't study the other answer in detail, but at first glance the derivation in my answer seems much simpler. Yes the Dawson integral is just another error function, and the derived formula doesn't really seem to be simpler than the original formula in this case, but in some cases the terms of the sum in the derived formula are simpler than the terms in the original sum. I didn't understand the link you referenced as I don't believe the Dirac comb method can be used when $f(0)$ is not finite and $\text{Ci}(0)=-\infty$.

Comment: Metamorphy said “ Basically the idea is to use [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_comb); the above is somewhat more rigorous” , so I though it would relate.

Comment: @TymaGaidash Perhaps it does in some way. Note the $-\frac{1}{2}\,f(0)$ in formula (2) above which subtracts off the contribution of the tooth of the Dirac comb at $x=0$ which only works when $f(0)$ is finite. Perhaps there's a more complicated way to remove the contribution of the tooth of the Dirac comb at $x=0$ when $f(0)$ isn't finite?

Comment: I have little experience with the Dirac Comb, so I don’t know. Do you know if there is a closed form of $$\sum_{x=0}^\infty x e^{-tx^2}$$? I may be able to get an integral representation using [this Jacobi Theta function](https://functions.wolfram.com/EllipticFunctions/EllipticThetaPrime3/02/)?

Comment: Try a limit. The partial sums for this will give an integral representation.