# Properties of $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} {\frac {{\ln}k} {k!}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form

Consider the following infinite sum:
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} {\frac {\ln k} {k!}} 
$$

(It is easy to show that it converges since ${\frac {\ln x} x}$ has a maximum.)

- Does it have a name?
- Can it be expressed in a closed form?
- Do we know if it's rational or not?

Comment: Do you think that you can link this with infinite products ?

Comment: It doesn't have any specific name, but I believe it can be expressed in a closed form.

Comment: See [this AOPS](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h1464238p8468896) problem. Please also [add more detail](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 2):

Let’s find an integral representation using @John Barber’s technique in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4255028/how-to-evaluate-sum-limits-x-0-infty-texterfcx-1-16199904794712636353). Now appears the [digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function):

\begin{align*}\sum_1^\infty \frac{\ln(n)}{n!} &=\int_1^\infty\lfloor x \rfloor \frac d{dx} \frac{\ln(x)}{x!}dx\\
&=\int_1^\infty \lfloor x\rfloor \left(\frac1{xx!}-\frac{\ln(x)ψ(x+1)}{x!}\right)dx\\
&= \int_1^\infty \frac{\lfloor x\rfloor}{xx!}dx -\int_1^\infty\frac{\lfloor x\rfloor\ln(x)ψ(x+1)}{x!}dx\\
&=-0.603782862791487988416183810982450548304170153164991021772413211382272284100525569478213750246…\end{align*}

Here is [proof](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+floor%28x%29%28%28x%21+-+x+%CE%93%281+%2B+x%29+log%28x%29+polygamma%280%2C+1+%2B+x%29%29%2F%28x+%28x%21%29%5E2%29%29+from+0+to+20) of the result.

Here is a visual representation of the constant. [Here is an interactive graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/is2jzh62en) too:

[image]

The “closed” form is nothing more than the [$\text A306243$ constant](https://oeis.org/A306243) unrelated to the above technique

equal to

> $$\ln(\exp(1/2*\ln(2*\exp(1/3*\ln(3*\exp(1/4*\ln(4*\exp(...))))))))$$

Please correct me and give me feedback!

Comment: How do you prove your first equation? Also how does it lead to the identity listed in OEIS? I can't follow this, but I gave +1 because that identity is quite remarkable (and I've verified it numerically to 10 digits.)

Comment: @JairTaylor See the linked question’s answer from John Barber please. The OEIS is separate.