# Is it possible to find the value of $\sum_{n = 0}^\infty n \int_{n}^{n+1}e^{-x^2}dx$?

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series

I want to calculate
$$
 \sum_{n = 0}^\infty n \int_{n}^{n+1}e^{-x^2}dx.
$$

Since
$$
\sum_{n = 0}^\infty n \int_{n}^{n+1}e^{-x^2}dx \leq \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \int_{n}^{n+1}xe^{-x^2}dx = \int_0^\infty xe^{-x^2} dx
$$
and $\int_0^\infty
xe^{x^2}dx = 1/2$, it is followed that the sum converges to some value.
But I have a trouble to find this value.

What I tried:

- Since $e^{-(n+1)^2} \leq \int_n^{n+1} e^{-x^2} dx \leq e^{-n^2}$,
  $$
  \sum_{n = 0}^\infty ne^{-(n+1)^2} \leq \sum_{n = 0}^\infty n \int_{n}^{n+1}e^{-x^2}dx \leq \sum_{n = 0}^\infty ne^{-n^2}
  $$

Please some help or advice. Thank you.

Comment: Your value of $0.1619…$ looks like [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4255028/how-to-evaluate-sum-limits-x-0-infty-texterfcx-1-16199904794712636353). Possible duplicate?

Comment: It can be written $\int_0^\infty \lfloor x\rfloor \,e^{-x^2}\,\mathrm d x$. But why do you think it can be simplified?

Comment: Yes, this is what I was looking for. I did not do enough research. My apologies and thank you !

Comment: This is an interesting question. I've closed it as a duplicate of another (interesting) question. But I note that there is a difference of exactly $1$ between the answer of this question and that question.